# Can I show a profile on contact summary page

Tags: civimember, contact-summary-editor

I would like to show membership details on the contact summary screen - type, status, start date - using the contact layout editor. I can create a profile for membership, but this isn't available to add, and membership fields can't be added to a block, it seems.  As you can have multiple memberships for a contact I can see why it might be tricky. Is it possible to show membership info on the summary screen using the UI?

Comment: Are you using Drupal. I 'think' you can add Views blocks via Contact Summary Layout Editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you install the Extended Reports extension (available from in-app download), you can place Extended Reports as a block using Contact Layout Editor.

See the screenshot below - I'm using the "Extended Report - Membership Price Set Report" template to generate this report.  Under the report's **Display Options** tab, I clicked **Make available for contact summary page**.

[image]

Comment: You'll have to explain that, please. I edited the question to add using the contact summary layout editor as maybe my question wasn't clear.

Comment: @AndyClark Your question was perfectly clear; I forgot that this functionality is limited to Extended Reports.  I've rewritten and fleshed out my answer, hope this does the trick!

Comment: Thanks, Jon got this working!

Answer (score 4):

My old answer is still valid, but the preferred answer in 2022 is to use Search Kit and Form Builder.  It's more flexible, and can be used to add almost any data to a block on the summary tab.

#### Setup

- Enable Search Kit and Form Builder in **Administer menu » System Settings » Extensions**.

#### Search Kit

- Go to **Search menu » Search Kit**.
- Press **New Search** at the top right.
- Set *Search for* to **Contacts** and add **With (required)** - **Contact Memberships** (screenshot item 1).
- Use the column **Add** button (item 2) to add the columns you'd like.  Do *not* filter by contact ID at this time - though you may filter on other criteria in the *Where* section (item 3), e.g. for certain membership types only.
- Choose a name for this search (item 4) and press **Save** (item 5).
- Click the Display **Add** (item 6) and select a **Table**. From here you can customize the column names, add links to the memberships, etc.  When you're done, press **Save** again (item 5).

[image: Search Kit admin screen]

#### Form Builder

- Go to **Administer menu » Customize Data and Screens » Form Builder**.
- Click on the **Search Forms** tab.
- Click **New Search Form** and select the search with the name you just saved, using the *Table* display.
- Add a block title, then check the **Add to Contact Summary Page** box, selecting **as block**.
- Select **Filter on Contact** and press **Save**.

You can now enter the Contact Layout Editor (you can add this under **Add New** in the *Extensions* screen if you don't have it already) and drop your new block into a summary tab.